# Display search results in different pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Ajax Search Lite plugin to search for something through my posts, and I want that when I search something, it displays 10 posts per page but with the option to view the next 10, and so on. I tried setting in the reading settings 10 posts per page, but it shows only the first 10 and there is no option to see the next 10.

This is the code in my search.php

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]'); ?>
    <?php
            if (have_posts()) : //se ci sono post
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
            ?>
            <article class="post">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>      
            <h3><?php the_content(); ?></h3>                                           
            </article>
            <?php  endwhile; 
            else :
                echo '</br><p> No results</p>';
            endif;?>
```

Comment: it's not about setting it's about ur code can u show some code which are u using ..... and also checvk ur plugin setting bez i can't understand why u put this on here first check ur consol and code

Comment: I added some code.

Comment: here in ur code r u find pagination code?